# Use value of parameter outside of callback function (undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which uses a callback:

```
photoUploadLoad(e.target.result, ".upload-photos-container", function(resizedImg){});
```

And I want to use `resizedImg` outside of the function, like so:

```
  $(emptyPhotos()[0]).attr('src', resizedImg);
```

this is the photoUploadLoad function:

```
function photoUploadLoad(imgUpload, element, callback) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = imgUpload;
  img.onload = function() {
    $(element).removeClass("loading");
    var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var iw=img.width;
    var ih=img.height;
    var scale=Math.min((maxW/iw),(maxH/ih));
    var iwScaled=iw*scale;
    var ihScaled=ih*scale;
    canvas.width=iwScaled;
    canvas.height=ihScaled;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,iwScaled,ihScaled);
    img.src=canvas.toDataURL();
    callback(img.src);
  };
}
```

but keep getting undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: `$(emptyPhotos()[0]).attr('src', function(resizedImg){});`

Comment: Added the function that was missing @AlivetoDie

Comment: @AlivetoDie that function makes no sense. First argument is `index`

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs where should I put this?

Comment: Not clear what *"outside the function"* really means or how you expect the implementation to work

Comment: Why don't you using a global variable ?

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh because it totally wont help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onload` is **asynchronous**

You need to do it inside the anonymous function you pass in as `callback`.

```
photoUploadLoad(e.target.result, ".upload-photos-container", function(resizedImg){
    $(emptyPhotos()[0]).attr('src', resizedImg);
});
```

Comment: Don't want to run it inside the function

Comment: But `onload` is asynchronous. Goes back to clarification of exactly what it is you are trying to do

Comment: One alternative would be to use a promise that gets resolved in the function.

Comment: @user1937021 there is pretty much no other option, your callback is async